# How to make sap.m.Text focusable?

Tags: sapui5, accessibility

Simple problem in fact.

I am displaying some Text using `sap.m` or `sap.ui.commons` elements.
I cannot access any of them using the arrows (cursors).
I succeed navigating to input fields, rows in table but **not** Text.

I looked for any help on the net but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i grasp the question right, then the desire is to have a click event for `sap.m.Text`. I.e. a click on a sap.m.Text control triggers a event which leads to a method in the corresponding controller of the view in which the control sits.

`sap.m.Text` does not feature any `click` event by standard. instead please use `sap.m.Link`. `sap.m.Link` has the `press` event which is a `click` event. e.g. in a xml view:

```
...
  <Link
    text="clickMe"
    press="onClickMethod">
  </Link>
...
```

Comment: Hi,So if I understand you right, I need to insert text as a sap.m.Link element. So it is a trick....and I am trying so many tricks in order to access the text element via cursors.Thank you very much!. Best Regards.